# Huge geoJSON file -- cannot even edit

Tags: json, memory, leaflet, geojson

I have a geoJSON file that needs to be edited. For example, I need to do a Find and Replace operation.  However, I cannot even open the file (150 MB) in some applications.  With TextEdit (I'm on a Mac), I can open the file, but the app stops responding and freezes almost immediately when I try any Find and Replace operation.

The file contains data (Points) that I'd like to map (I think I will use Leaflet), so eventually I need to transfer the file to my server.  Given the size of the file, will I run into any problems there and then mapping the points in a browser?

Any advice or pointers on what to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands) on replacing text from the command line.  You should be able to use `sed` to replace those instances without having to load it in memory (I think).

Comment: Dafuq, why was a downvoted?  Thank you Stack Overflow trolls! <3

Comment: Very nice! Thanks--I'll give it a go. (BTW I just up voted you and will mark as correct answer).